# GC Generations - Collecting issue

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection

Given the following code:

```
namespace GcDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<object>();
            Console.WriteLine("list is in {0} generation.", GC.GetGeneration(list));
            GC.Collect();
            Console.WriteLine("list is in {0} generation.", GC.GetGeneration(list));
            GC.Collect();
            list.Add(new object());
            Console.WriteLine("list is in {0} generation. object is in {1} generation.", GC.GetGeneration(list), GC.GetGeneration(list[0]));
            GC.Collect(0);
            Console.WriteLine("list is in {0} generation. object is in {1} generation.", GC.GetGeneration(list), GC.GetGeneration(list[0]));

        }
    }
}
```

The list object is in Gen 2 while it is the only reference list[0] object that is in gen 0. How come it knows not to collect it in GC.Collect(0) ?

Comment: Did you expect the `object` instance to be collected?

Comment: Why would it be? It is still rooted and thus not eligible for collection. If gen0 objects could not reliably be rooted by objects in gen1 or 2 then the entire idea of generations would be pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx) has a simple writeup of how it works; read the "Making Generations Work with Write Barriers" section. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2009/03/02/back-to-basics-generational-garbage-collection.aspx) is another good blog post explaining the techinque in more detail.

The executive summary is the CLR emits code so it can detect when the Gen2 object was written to. It records the write into a data structure (the "card table") that it inspects when doing the Gen0 collection; this allows it to find the Gen2 -> Gen0 reference without the full cost of walking all objects in memory.

Comment: thanks a lot Jason, you helped me get the subject in a clear and understandable way.

Answer (score 1):

Am I right, that your question is, why the GC doesn't collection `list[0]`?

If so, then the answer is, because `list` internally has an reference to your created object (because `List<T>` internally has an array `T[]` to hold the items).

So your reference chain looks like that: `Program.Main()` -> `list` -> `list[0]`, and therefore the GC cannot (and should not) collect this object, regardless in which generation your objects are.

**EDIT**: Where you start the collection of gen 0, ... `list[0]` is in gen 0 + referenced (see above) => the GC *does not* collect `list[0]`, but moves it to gen 1.

Comment: But I collect only generation 0, the list is in gen 2, how does the GC know not to collect list[0]?

Comment: Hence the GC does not see the reference of the list[0] to the object, and still it “somehow” know not to collect the object and even to promote it to Gen 1. The question is the “somehow”?

Comment: As I described in the answer, `list` *internally* has a reference to `list[0]` =>  the GC "knows" `list[0]` through `list`.

Comment: ... see https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs#L49 and https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs#L90 for the Mono `List<T>` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The primary rule is pretty simple, an object gets collected when there are no references left to it.  The object you added to the list cannot get collected, the list has a reference to it.  The list cannot get collected, your code has a reference to it.  All the way up to the last statement.  And every time to force a collection, you force the objects to move into the next generation.

The only thing that's possibly confounding about this is that the garbage collector can see that the list stores a reference to the object.  It most certainly does.  Necessarily so, you wouldn't want the object to disappear randomly.  A very big part of what the CLR does is provide the garbage collector with the information it needs to discover this as quickly as possible.

Possibly more confounding is that it can also see that your code has a reference to the list.  That's an important part of what the jitter does, it constructs a table that says what part of the code is referencing a local variable.  You cannot see that in your snippet since the last statement references the list.